# Как из нативки Android проверить целостность клиента?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем добрый день!
Есть проект, в котором значительная часть проверок производится на стороне клиента Android. Для защиты от фрода решили часть логики перенести в обфусцированную  нативную библиотеку. Это работает так: запрос на сервер подписывается хэшом с солью, данный хэш генерится в нативке. Однако все равно некоторые возможности фрода остались в java коде, чтобы их устранить, пришлось бы полностью переписывать весь java код на натив. Можно ли из нативки проверить, вносились ли какие-то изменения в java код  клиента? И можно ли из нативки получить imei устройства?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что если из ndk вызывать java функции, которые могут быть изменены и сверять ожидаемый результат с фактическим. Или пусть этот результат участвует в процессе подписи запросов. Результат изменился - подпись не валидна.

Answer (score 3):

Все что на клиентской стороне можно взломать, хоть сделаешь с помощью java или C++. Ищите возможности антифрода на стороне бэка. Даже если что-то сделаете это только отсрочит обход(Ну максимум от скрип киди спасет).